# Access to link #options key on twig template

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

How can i have access to the #options key of array on the twig template?

I'm trying to check if the language is the current one and then set it as active.

My code looks like:

```
<ul class="headerbar__text--language navbar-right">
{%- for key, item in links -%}
  {%
    set link_class = [
      item.set_active_class ? 'active',
    ]
  %}
  <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(key|clean_class).addClass(link_class) }}>
    {{ dump(item) }}
    {%- if item.link -%}
      {{ item.link }}
    {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
      <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
    {%- else -%}
      {{ item.text }}
    {%- endif -%}
  </li>
{%- endfor -%}
```

But the class is not set. As you can see, there is a dump and the result is following:

```
array (size=4)
'link' => 
    array (size=5)
      '#type' => string 'link' (length=4)
      '#title' => string 'German' (length=6)
      '#options' => 
        array (size=5)
          'language' => 
            object(Drupal\language\Entity\ConfigurableLanguage)[1623]
              ...
          'attributes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'query' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'ajax' => null
          'set_active_class' => boolean true
      '#url' => 
        object(Drupal\Core\Url)[1629]
          protected 'urlGenerator' => 
            object(Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator)[227]
              ...
          protected 'urlAssembler' => null
          protected 'accessManager' => null
          protected 'routeName' => string '<front>' (length=7)
          protected 'routeParameters' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'options' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'external' => boolean false
          protected 'unrouted' => boolean false
          protected 'uri' => null
          protected 'internalPath' => string '' (length=0)
          protected '_serviceIds' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      '#ajax' => null
  'text' => string 'German' (length=6)
  'text_attributes' => 
    object(Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute)[1646]
      protected 'storage' => 
        array (size=1)
          'class' => 
            object(Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeArray)[1647]
              ...
  'attributes' => 
    object(Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute)[1649]
      protected 'storage' => 
        array (size=3)
          'hreflang' => 
            object(Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeString)[1650]
              ...
          'data-drupal-link-system-path' => 
            object(Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeString)[1651]
              ...
          'class' => 
            object(Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeArray)[1959]
              ...
```

I've tryed to access it with `link['#options']` or `link.options` or as you can see `link.set_active_class`, but all of them returns NULL.

So how i'm able to have access those attributes?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the structure of the dump, this should be working:

```
{%  set link_class = item.link['#options'].set_active_class ? 'active' %}
```